# Windows Phone - HTC - XamlParseException property Mode not found ApplicationBar

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I get XamlParseException on HTC Mazaa. The code below works fine on Nokia Phones and Emulators. If I remove Property `Mode` from `Applicationbar` it starts working on HTC Mazaa as well. Why is Mode Property not recognized when running on HTC Mazaa?

Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Minimized" ForegroundColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White"  IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity="0.9" >
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="About" Click="About_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Exception and Stacktrace below

```
The property Mode was not found in type ApplicationBar
 at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at JohnCO.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
   at JohnCO.MainPage..ctor()
```

If I try to do it pro-grammatically in C# like:

```
this.ApplicationBar.Mode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
```

I get exception as :

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMode' from assembly
 'Microsoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24EEC0D8C86CDA1E'
```

This is a weird problem happening on on HTC Mazaa. I haven't been able to try it on any other HTC phones. Above code works fine on bunch of NOKIA phones and Emulators.

This app is being developed using latest SDK `Windows Phone SDK 8.0, targeting 7.1 OS - WP7.x devices.`

The HTC Mazaa I am testing on has Windows Phone 7.5 Software version

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of installed OS on the HTC Mazaa? My guess you don't have Mango update (WP7.5) installed - the property Mode was not available in WP7.0.
Anyway, HTC Mazaa was a pre-production device provided only for developers, so there is a chance it won't work with the new SDK at all. Maybe you even don't have the final build of Windows Phone 7.5 build number 7720 installed.

Comment: In Settings -> System -> About it says Model : HTC Mazaa Software : Windows Phone 7.5. So I think it has Mango Update.

Comment: And the version number is 7.1.7720 or newer? I guess the problem is really based in the developer device, that might behave erratically.

Comment: It says OS version 7649.WM7_DevicesPlat(btsqalab).20110523-741. Firmware revision number 1600.0900.7649.0. Actually I saw a bunch of XamlParseException happening at the same location in code in production version of app, figured out by looking at the crash reports stack trace from Windows live account.

Comment: If it says "OS version 7649", it means it's some kind of WP7.5 beta and it's possible that the property Mode is not yet implemented. I would recommend asking on XDA developers, how to flash your phone to latest OS: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=606

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. What I still dont understand is why would it show up 21 times in crash reports I downloaded from Windows Store?